# Syntax of RLMArray?

Tags: objective-c, generics, realm

What does

```
@property RLMArray<Dog *><Dog> *dogs;
```

stands for? (taken from [the Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/))

---

Remark: in order to have an array of `Dog`s, I would naturally have done instead

```
@property RLMArray<Dog> *dogs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Dog *>` is an [Objective-C generic](http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/), whereas `<Dog>` is a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) dictating which type of `RLMObject` subclass will be added to the `RLMArray`.

It's not strictly necessary to add the generic (i.e. the code will compile without it), but it definitely makes working with the array nicer. The protocol however, is required.